# cannot open source file opencv2/opencv.hpp in visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, opencv

I tried to run this program.
and I got squiggly line under the include saying

> cannot open source file opencv2/opencv.hpp

I had added all the additional dependencies and file path for the additional include directories -

> $(C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2)

I am struck here and don't know how to resolve. Moreover I could not find the debug folder in the saved proj file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2\opencv.hpp "
#include "opencv2\imgcodecs.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  Mat img;
  VideoCapture cam(0);
  namdeWindow("camera");
while (1)
{
    cam >> img;
    imshow("camera", img);
    if (waitkey(1) == 27)
        break;
}

cam.release();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: just "C:\opencv\build\include"

Comment: I had tried it still i can't resolve still Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

I included the "using namespace cv;" above the main(). Strangely after I restarted the PC errors are gone.